# Strange behaviour referring to variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm seeing some odd behaviour using dplyr when referring to variables in a tbl. Perhaps I need to approach this differently or perhaps this is a bug. Perhaps you can help me!

This works:

```
data <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
data <- as.tbl(data)
cut(data$x, breaks = 2)

[1] (0.991,5.5] (0.991,5.5] (0.991,5.5] (0.991,5.5] (0.991,5.5] (5.5,10]   
[7] (5.5,10]    (5.5,10]    (5.5,10]    (5.5,10]   
Levels: (0.991,5.5] (5.5,10]
```

This does not:

```
cut(data[, "x"], breaks = 2)
Error in cut.default(data[, "x"], breaks = 2) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Perhaps this is related to non standard evaluation used in dplyr. Any thoughts?

Thanks

David

Comment: That's because `data[, "x"]` returns a `tbl` rather a vector. Though I'm not sure if this intended behaviour or a bug. A debugging advice for the future, if you have some "bug" in some embedded function. start debugging from inside out, i.e., first see what happens when you do `data[, "x"]` and only then try it combined with `cut`.

Comment: Its intended by design for the moment but not sure is a feature. More info here https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/587

Comment: Thanks, I see. I did work it out in the meantime, but the thread mentioned does show that this will be a potentially nasty trap for the unsuspecting, who would assume `dat[, "x"]` and `dat[["x"]]` do the same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to close this up, by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/tbl-df.r#L114), it seems that `[.tbl_df` (unlike `[.data.frame`) *alsways* sets `drop = FALSE` and [doesn't let you](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/tbl-df.r#L116) to tell it otherwise

So when you do

```
data[, "x"]
```

[What actually happens](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/tbl-df.r#L118-L126) is

```
result <- .subset(data, "x")
class(result) <- c("tbl_df", "data.frame")
attr(result, "row.names") <- .set_row_names(nrow(data))
result
```

While you actually looked for was

```
.subset(data, "x")[[1]]
```

(In case `lnegth(j) == 1L`)

As mentioned in comments, this is already being discussed [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/587)